# How to say "welcome back" after the user comes back again

Tags: actions-on-google

I was trying the actions on goolge game SoundPet and noticed it was able to say "welcome back" when I played a second time though I never granted any permissions, can anyone tell me the simplest way to do this? Can you record a userID or something and then store that in a database for later reference? If so, how do you get the user ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is using conv.user.last.seen. It stores date value that user visit last time. If it is first time of user, it returns undefined.

For more information:

https://developers.google.com/actions/design/tips

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  if (conv.user.last.seen) {
    conv.ask(`Hey you're back...`);
  } else {
    conv.ask('Welcome to World Cities Trivia!...');
  }
}
```